# C - How to add a float variable to a string

Tags: c

I've got a variable that contains a floating number, how do I do about adding this to a string?

Something like this:

```
int main() {
    char postdata[] = "field1=";
    float mynumber = 123.12;
    postdata = postdata + mynumber;
    return 0;
}
```

I want the end  result to be "field1=123.1"

It doesnt seem to be as easy as postdata + mynumber :(

Comment: Look up the `sprintf` function, then go and purchase [K&R](http://www.amazon.co.uk/C-Programming-Language-2nd/dp/0131103628).

Comment: Note that C string manipulation can be really painful, because programmer is responsible for making sure there are no buffer overruns etc, *everywhere*. If you have the option, use something else. Simplest move away from pure C is to use a small subset of C++, especially `std::string`, in otherwise "C style" application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/):

```
char buffer[32];
sprintf(buffer, "%s%f", postdata, mynumber);
```

If you need one-digit precision:

```
char buffer[32];
sprintf(buffer, "%s%.1f", postdata, mynumber);
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/vzCnrP) is a working example.

Comment: Use `snprintf` for preference unless you want to make yourself vulnerable to buffer overrun errors.

Comment: Since you have a fixed size char array buffer, using `snprintf` is very easy: `snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, .....`